# Angular - parse json string created by json dumps

Tags: javascript, json, angular, python-3.x, typescript

I couldn't  find a helpful solution.

I work in python 3.6 (django rest-framwork) server side and angular 5 client side.

At the server:

```
class TypesView(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        a = ['Cat','Dog']
        j = json.dumps(a)
        return Response(data=j, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I am trying to parse this at the client:

```
  public getAnimalRaces(): Observable<string[]>{
     const path = environment.apiEndpoint + "animals/races/"
    return this._http_client.get<string[]>(path)
  }
```

but I keep getting:
Error trying to diff '["Cat", "Dog"]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

This is what Being returned to the client:

```
"[\"Cat\", \"Dog\"]"
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to iterate on a string.

You need to parse the response as JSON which will turn the response into an array which you can then use with `*ngFor` in the template for example.

```
this._http_client.get<string[]>(path)
  .map((res) => JSON.parse(res));
```

Comment: Only thing different is :  this._http_client.get<string> instead of string[]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your response is stringified. In order to make it work, you have to send it as plain JSON on server side, or treat it as string and use `JSON.parse()` on client side.